# Monotone Convergence Theorem with given a1 and a2

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question regarding the Monotone Convergence Theorem which goes like this,

a<sub>1</sub>=2

a<sub>2</sub>=3

a<sub>n+1</sub>=$\frac{a_n +a_{n-1}}{(n+1)n}$       for n>=2

Does the sequence a<sub>n</sub> converge?

So i tried this by taking a look at values a<sub>3</sub> a<sub>4</sub> a<sub>5</sub> using the formula and it does look like a decreasing function which is bounded by 0. Then i tried to show that the function was decreasing by taking the difference of a<sub>n+1</sub> - a<sub>n</sub> but this is where i got stuck. I'm not sure how to show this function is decreasing and bounded by 0. What should be my take on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $0\le a_{n-2}\le a_{n-1} \le a_n$ (which you actually have from $a_3,a_4,a_5$). You then have $a_{n+1} \ge 0$ and
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} - a_n 
&= \frac{a_n + a_{n-1}}{(n+1)n} - \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{n(n-1)}\\
&\le \frac{a_n + a_{n-1}}{(n+1)n} - \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{n(n\color{red}{+}1)}\\
&\le \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{(n+1)n} + \frac{a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}}{n(n+1)}\\
&\le 0.
\end{align*}
Due to the Induction Principle, this sequence is positive and decreases after $n=3$. Therefore, it converges. Moreover, the limit is given by
$$0\le l = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n+a_{n-1}}{(n+1)n} \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2a_3}{(n+1)n} = 0,$$
ie. $l=0$.